# Not Receiving Data from Route C#

Tags: c#, .net, routes, attachment, memorystream

I'm attempting to return an image from a server route, but I'm getting one that is 0 bytes. I suspect it has something to do with how I'm using the `MemoryStream`. Here's my code:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("edit")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Edit(int pdfFileId)
{
    var pdf = await PdfFileModel.PdfDbOps.QueryAsync((p => p.Id == pdfFileId));

    IEnumerable<Image> pdfPagesAsImages = PdfOperations.PdfToImages(pdf.Data, 500);
    MemoryStream imageMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    pdfPagesAsImages.First().Save(imageMemoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response.Content = new StreamContent(imageMemoryStream);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = pdf.Filename,
        DispositionType = "attachment"
    };
    return response;
}
```

Through debugging I have verified that the `PdfToImages` method is working and that `imageMemoryStream` gets filled with data from the line

```
pdfPagesAsImages.First().Save(imageMemoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
```

However in running it, I receive an attachment that is properly named but is 0 bytes. What do I need to change in order to receive the whole file? I think it's something simple but I'm not sure what. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you have to set stream position to 0? `imageMemoryStream.Position = 0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After writing to the `MemoryStream`, `Flush` it then set `Position` to 0:

```
imageMemoryStream.Flush();
imageMemoryStream.Position = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rewind `MemoryStream` to beginning before passing it to response. But you'd better use `PushStreamContent`:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
response.Content = new PushStreamContent(async (stream, content, context) => 
  {
    var pdf = await PdfFileModel.PdfDbOps.QueryAsync(p => p.Id == pdfFileId);
    content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
      FileName = pdf.Filename,
      DispositionType = "attachment"
    };

    PdfOperations.PdfToImages(pdf.Data, 500).First().Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
  }, "image/png");
return response;
```

Comment: What's the warrant for using `PushStreamContent`?

Comment: No need to allocate extra memory for `MemoryStream`.

Comment: In testing your code it comes through inline, not as an attachment. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Also it seems to hang, with a spinning wheel in the tab header.

Comment: As to content-disposition - check via http capture which headers are sent. About "hanging" - can't really tell without debugging.